# Can anyone help me how to min-height in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to use `minHeight` in one of my `divs` but it does not work and I don't know why...

```
<div id="countries">
  <div class="fixed">
    <div class="country" style="marging-left:0px;"></div>
    <div class="country"></div>
    <div class="country"></div>
    <div class="country"></div>
    <div class="country"></div>
    <div class="country"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#countries").css("min-height", "100px");
  $(".fixed").css("minHeight", "100px");
  $(".country").css("height", $(window).height() * 0.4);    
</script>
```

I don't know why the countries `minHeight` does not apply. even the `.country` is over size of the "#countries".
I also used:

```
$("#countries").css("minHeight","100px");    
$("#countries").attr("style","min-height:100px");
```

and it did not work at all.

Comment: can you please provide jsfiddle

Comment: it is working means Jquery is working

Comment: I think you mean maxHeight. No?

Comment: What effect are you trying to achieve? There is nothing wrong with `$("#countries").css("minHeight","100px");` (this will work), but it might not be doing what you are expecting it to do.

@Amina, that's what I thought originally, but I'm not sure now. I think he might be trying to set a min-height for #countries so that it's bigger than the ".country" divs it contains, in which case the issue is with the totally different methods he uses to define the height of each bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand about :

1. `min-height` is the minimum height of an element if it doesn't have child elements then it doesn't shrink after a `min-height`.
2. `max-height` is the element that if the height is exceeded then scroll with be applied.

So, the only change to make is the css property:

```
$("#countries").css("max-height", "100px");
//-------------------^^^^^^^^^^-------------this one.
```

Demo:

```js
$('#countries1').css('min-height', '100px');
$('#countries2').css('max-height', '100px');
```

```css
#countries1,
#countries2 {
  width: 100px;
  float:left;
  background:red;
  overflow:auto;
  margin-right:10px;
}
#countries1 div{background:green;}
#countries2 div{background:green; border-bottom:solid 1px black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="countries1">
  Min-Height: no scroll.
  <div class="fixed">
    <div class="country" style="marging-left:0px;"></div>
    <div class="country">aaa</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="countries2">
  Max-Height:has scroll
  <div class="fixed">
    <div class="country" style="marging-left:0px;"></div>
    <div class="country">aaa</div>
    <div class="country">bbb</div>
    <div class="country">ccc</div>
    <div class="country">ddd</div>
    <div class="country">eee</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess you are looking for `max-height`, which restricts the height of the container to a maximum of `100px`:

```
$(function () {
  $("#countries").css("max-height", "100px");
});
```

Also wrapping it inside `$(function() {})` is safe.

Answer (score 0):

you can use !important declarations as it would help easily override normal specificity

```
 <div id="countries" style="border: black 1px solid">
        <div class="fixed">
            <div class="country">Some Sample 1</div>
            <div class="country">Some Sample 2</div>
            <div class="country">Some Sample 3</div>
            <div class="country">Some Sample 4</div>
            <div class="country">Some Sample 5 </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <style>
        .cutomMinHeight
        {
            min-height: 200px !important;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#countries").addClass("cutomMinHeight");
        $(".fixed").addClass("cutomMinHeight");
    </script>
```

working example on jsfiddle

> https://jsfiddle.net/u7caty0o/1/

Hope that helps.